# Problems when validating XML and DTD

Tags: xml, dtd

I have made this list of recipes, but for some reason I get a ton of error messages when I try to validate the documents in Oxygen XML Editor. 
Oxygen gives me the following errors:

element type "ingredients" must not be declared more than once
element type "name" must not be declared more than once
element type "quantity" must not be declared more than once
unexpected element "ingredients". The content of the parent element must match:
(name+, ingredients+, quantity+, decoration, instructions, neccessity, preparation)

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE recipes SYSTEM "recipes.dtd">

<recipes>
    <cocktail>

      <name>Hells Bells</name>

      <ingredients>Batida de Coco</ingredients>
      <quantity> 4cl </quantity>

      <ingredients>caramel sirup</ingredients>
      <quantity> 2 cl </quantity>

      <ingredients>Milk</ingredients>
      <quantity> 8 cl </quantity>

      <ingredients>Strawberry puree</ingredients>
      <quantity> 4 cl </quantity>

      <decoration>Decoration: Strawberry blood with spiders.</decoration>
      <instructions>Instructions: All ingredients should be shaken.</instuctions>

      </cocktail> 

      <cocktail>

        <name>Feuerzangenbowle</name>

        <ingredients>red wine</ingredients>
        <quantity> 1000 ml </quantity>

        <ingredients>cinnamon</ingredients>
        <quantity> 1 </quantity>

        <ingredients>Carnations</ingredients>
        <quantity> 3 </quantity>

        <necessity>500 ml Pott</necessity>

        <preparation>Season with cinnamon stick and cloves.</preparation>

    </cocktail> 

    <appetizer>

      <name>Fresh glass</name>

      <ingredients>avocado</ingredients>
      <quantity> 1 </quantity>

      <ingredients>salmon</ingredients>
      <quantity> 100 g </quantity> 

      <ingredients>chives</ingredients>
      <quantity> stems </quantity>

      <ingredients>lemon</ingredients>
      <quantity> 1 </quantity>

    </appetizer>

    <appetizer>

      <name>Merceiles Hummus</name>

      <ingredients>Chickpeas</ingredients>
      <quantity> 400 g </quantity>

      <ingredients>olive oil</ingredients>
      <quantity> 2 TS </quantity>

      <ingredients>salt</ingredients>
      <quantity> 1 TS </quantity>

      <ingredients>Pepper powder</ingredients>
      <quantity> 1 TS </quantity>

   </appetizer>

   <maindish>

      <name>Pickled salmon</name>

      <ingredients>salmon</ingredients>
      <quantity> 2,5 kg </quantity>

      <ingredients>pepper</ingredients>
      <quantity> 1 TS </quantity>

      <ingredients>salt</ingredients>
      <quantity> 4 TS </quantity>

      <ingredients>honey</ingredients>
      <quantity> 4 TS </quantity>

   </maindish>

   <maindish>

      <name>Beef fillet</name>

      <ingredients>Beef fillet</ingredients>
      <quantity> 1,5 kg </quantity>

      <ingredients>Butterfelt</ingredients>
      <quantity> 20 g </quantity>

      <ingredients>thyme</ingredients>
      <quantity> 4 branches </quantity>

   </maindish>

   <dessert>

      <name>Chocolate Muffins</name>

      <ingredients>chocolate</ingredients>
      <quantity> 225 g </quantity>

      <ingredients>butter</ingredients>
      <quantity> 115 g </quantity>

      <ingredients>vanillasuger</ingredients>
      <quantity> 1 TS </quantity>

      <ingredients>sugar</ingredients>
      <quantity> 100 g </quantity>

   </dessert>

   <dessert>

     <name>Tiramisu</name>

     <ingredients>sugar</ingredients>
     <quantity> 100 g </quantity>

     <ingredients>yolk</ingredients>
     <quantity> 4 </quantity>

     <ingredients>egg whites</ingredients>
     <quantity> 2 </quantity>

     <ingredients>Amaretto</ingredients>
     <quantity> 2 cl </quantity>

   </dessert>

</recipes>
```

And here is the DTD:

```
<!-- DTD document recipes.xml  -->

<!ELEMENT recipes (cocktail+, appetizer+, maindish+, dessert+)>

<!ELEMENT cocktail (name+, ingredients+, quantity+, decoration, instructions, neccessity, preparation)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT ingredients (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT quantity (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT decoration (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT instructions (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT neccessity (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT preparation (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT appetizer (name+, ingredients+, quantity+)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT ingredients (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT quantity (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT maindish (name+, ingredients+, quantity+)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT ingredients (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT quantity (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT dessert (name+, ingredients+, quantity+)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT ingredients (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT quantity (#PCDATA)>
```

I really don't know what to do anymore and would really appreciate your help!
Thank you in advance for your answers!

P.S - new to XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> element type "ingredients" must not be declared more than once
> element type "name" must not be declared more than once
> element type "quantity" must not be declared more than once
> ```

These errors are pretty self explanatory; you can only declare an element once in the DTD (the `<!ELEMENT` declarations).

> ```
> unexpected element "ingredients". The content of the parent element must match:
> (name+, ingredients+, quantity+, decoration, instructions, neccessity, preparation)
> ```

This error is saying that the `ingredients` element is out of place. The parent of `ingredients` (`cocktail`) must match the model in the DTD. In this case, `cocktail` must have:

- one or more `name` elements followed by
- one or more `ingredients` elements followed by
- one or more `quantity` elements followed by
- exactly one `decoration` element followed by
- exactly one `instructions` element followed by
- exactly one `neccessity` element followed by
- exactly one `preparation` element

Looking at your XML, this doesn't look like what you want. You probably want something that looks more like this:

```
(name+, (ingredients, quantity)+, decoration?, instructions?, necessity?, preparation?)
```

This is:

- one or more `name` elements followed by
- one or more

  - exactly one `ingredients` element followed by
  - exactly one `quantity` element
- followed by
- zero or one `decoration` element followed by
- zero or one `instructions` element followed by
- zero or one `necessity` element followed by
- zero or one `preparation` element

You spelled `necessity` differently in your DTD and XML; they need to match.

You also misspelled the `instructions` end tag in the first `cocktail`.

The part where `ingredients` followed by `quantity` one or more times should also be updated in the models for `appetizer`, `maindish`, and `dessert`.

Here's an updated DTD:

```
<!ELEMENT recipes (cocktail+, appetizer+, maindish+, dessert+)>

<!ELEMENT cocktail (name+, (ingredients, quantity)+, decoration?, instructions?, necessity?, preparation?)>
<!ELEMENT appetizer (name+, (ingredients, quantity)+)>
<!ELEMENT maindish (name+, (ingredients, quantity)+)>
<!ELEMENT dessert (name+, (ingredients, quantity)+)>

<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT ingredients (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT quantity (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT decoration (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT instructions (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT necessity (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT preparation (#PCDATA)>
```

and XML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE recipes SYSTEM "recipes.dtd">
<recipes>
    <cocktail>

        <name>Hells Bells</name>

        <ingredients>Batida de Coco</ingredients>
        <quantity> 4cl </quantity>

        <ingredients>caramel sirup</ingredients>
        <quantity> 2 cl </quantity>

        <ingredients>Milk</ingredients>
        <quantity> 8 cl </quantity>

        <ingredients>Strawberry puree</ingredients>
        <quantity> 4 cl </quantity>

        <decoration>Decoration: Strawberry blood with spiders.</decoration>
        <instructions>Instructions: All ingredients should be shaken.</instructions>

    </cocktail> 

    <cocktail>

        <name>Feuerzangenbowle</name>

        <ingredients>red wine</ingredients>
        <quantity> 1000 ml </quantity>

        <ingredients>cinnamon</ingredients>
        <quantity> 1 </quantity>

        <ingredients>Carnations</ingredients>
        <quantity> 3 </quantity>

        <necessity>500 ml Pott</necessity>

        <preparation>Season with cinnamon stick and cloves.</preparation>

    </cocktail> 

    <appetizer>

        <name>Fresh glass</name>

        <ingredients>avocado</ingredients>
        <quantity> 1 </quantity>

        <ingredients>salmon</ingredients>
        <quantity> 100 g </quantity> 

        <ingredients>chives</ingredients>
        <quantity> stems </quantity>

        <ingredients>lemon</ingredients>
        <quantity> 1 </quantity>

    </appetizer>

    <appetizer>

        <name>Merceiles Hummus</name>

        <ingredients>Chickpeas</ingredients>
        <quantity> 400 g </quantity>

        <ingredients>olive oil</ingredients>
        <quantity> 2 TS </quantity>

        <ingredients>salt</ingredients>
        <quantity> 1 TS </quantity>

        <ingredients>Pepper powder</ingredients>
        <quantity> 1 TS </quantity>

    </appetizer>

    <maindish>

        <name>Pickled salmon</name>

        <ingredients>salmon</ingredients>
        <quantity> 2,5 kg </quantity>

        <ingredients>pepper</ingredients>
        <quantity> 1 TS </quantity>

        <ingredients>salt</ingredients>
        <quantity> 4 TS </quantity>

        <ingredients>honey</ingredients>
        <quantity> 4 TS </quantity>

    </maindish>

    <maindish>

        <name>Beef fillet</name>

        <ingredients>Beef fillet</ingredients>
        <quantity> 1,5 kg </quantity>

        <ingredients>Butterfelt</ingredients>
        <quantity> 20 g </quantity>

        <ingredients>thyme</ingredients>
        <quantity> 4 branches </quantity>

    </maindish>

    <dessert>

        <name>Chocolate Muffins</name>

        <ingredients>chocolate</ingredients>
        <quantity> 225 g </quantity>

        <ingredients>butter</ingredients>
        <quantity> 115 g </quantity>

        <ingredients>vanillasuger</ingredients>
        <quantity> 1 TS </quantity>

        <ingredients>sugar</ingredients>
        <quantity> 100 g </quantity>

    </dessert>

    <dessert>

        <name>Tiramisu</name>

        <ingredients>sugar</ingredients>
        <quantity> 100 g </quantity>

        <ingredients>yolk</ingredients>
        <quantity> 4 </quantity>

        <ingredients>egg whites</ingredients>
        <quantity> 2 </quantity>

        <ingredients>Amaretto</ingredients>
        <quantity> 2 cl </quantity>

    </dessert>

</recipes>
```